# Any links to information on the Ford Sync SDK?

Tags: iphone, smartdevicelink

This is a joint effort between Ford and Microsoft and it's about time they opened up the SDK to developers.

http://www.engadget.com/2009/12/18/ford-to-give-sync-some-app-store-flavor-opening-api-to-devs-in/

Will there be a .NET compatibile version of the SDK?

It sounds like you just have to be able to communicate via your application to it's API via bluetooth so the sky's the limit with developing apps on your iPhone, Android or even a bluetooth enabled Netbook.

Will this eventually be opened up to other automobile manufacturers or is Microsoft stuck to only licensing the Sync techology to the Ford platform?

If you have any inside information or details regarding this please post them.  Maybe some of the devs from the article are SO readers and can provide some more details on the tech / api.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave this answer so we can close this topic. If anyone is looking for information on how to develop applications to run on the SYNC platform using Applink (aka SmartDeviceLink), please go to our developer documentation [here](https://developer.ford.com/pages/develop)

Answer (score 0):

The Ford Sync API won't be opened to the development public until 2010.

Comment: I realize that as it says it in the linked article.  But there are people already developing using it as is also noted in the article so some information should start leaking out.

Answer (score -1):

I realize it's not quite what you're asking but the information [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/products/windows-embedded-automotive/default.mspx) may also be of some interest to you.